# Webpack and a legacy plugin that takes the real window object as an argument

Tags: jquery-plugins, webpack

I am migrating an app from Require.js to Webpack. Among the jQuery plugins that the app uses is [hc-sticky](https://github.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky). The [source file](https://github.com/somewebmedia/hc-sticky/blob/master/jquery.hc-sticky.js) of this plugin starts like this:

```js
(function($, window, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    // console.log shortcut
    var log = function(t){console.log(t)};

    var $window = $(window),
        document = window.document,
        $document = $(document);

    // detect IE version
    var ie = (function(){var undef, v = 3, div = document.createElement('div'),
```

The module built with Webpack breaks at the last line of the above fragment, because the `window` that is passed as an argument to the plugin turns out to be an empty object that doesn't have reference to the `document`.

Could you please advise how to integrate this plugin in the Webpack build? I searched, but failed to find a working solution. An attempt to substitute `this` for `window`:

```
{test: /jquery-hc-sticky/, loader: 'imports?this=>window'}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Honestly, with something that old without updates, just fork it. You can properly require jQuery and just change the `this` to `window` and it'll work.

Comment: Yeah, I removed `this`/`window` from the arguments entirely, and it worked. Just thought that maybe there is a cleaner solution.